# Jenkins Artifactory Plugin not working with recent Artifactory version

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

We have the following steps in our `Jenkinsfile` (trying to upload artifacts to our Artifactory server):

```
def server = script.Artifactory.server("our-artifactory-server-id")
def uploadSpec = """{
  "files": [
  {
    "pattern": "${sourcePath}",
    "target": "${targetPath}"
  }
 ]
}"""
server.upload(uploadSpec)
```

This used to work until we updated to a newer version of Artifactory. Ever since the update, we get the following error when running the build job:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 400
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.uploadFile(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:656)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:343)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.spec.SpecsHelper.deploy(SpecsHelper.java:291)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.spec.SpecsHelper.uploadArtifactsBySpec(SpecsHelper.java:65)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.invoke(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:189)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.invoke(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:130)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2750)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:181)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:52)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at ......remote call to docker-bc26fb0b91c4(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1554)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:281)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:839)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:987)
Caused: java.io.IOException: remote file operation failed: /home/jenkins/workspace/tration_feature_jenkinsfile-ANARWI2SDBPRVZNIYHCS6XKXIAD2SZ5ZTHM6DRXHYSARAQHPWEMQ at hudson.remoting.Channel@4c39a5aa:docker-bc26fb0b91c4
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:994)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:976)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.executors.GenericUploadExecutor.execution(GenericUploadExecutor.java:52)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.UploadStep$Execution.run(UploadStep.java:65)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.UploadStep$Execution.run(UploadStep.java:46)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:260)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Some background regarding our setup:

- Jenkins version `2.69`
- Artifactory version `5.8.4`
- Artifactory plugin version `2.14.0`
- the error started to appear with a recent update of Artifactory
- the Artifactory log shows no output for the error
- we are sitting behind a proxy, but `no_proxy` is set correctly, at least we can `curl https://...` to our Artifactory host
- we have self-signed certificates for Artifactory, but they should be properly added to the java truststore and the system truststore, since we can open `URLs` in java apps as well as with `curl` without any issues.

Any idea how we could debug this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a very similar issue and found the solution in the configuration of the Artifactory-Jenkins plugin (manage jenkins --> configure system --> artifactory).

What I did was changing the Artifactory server URL from:

```
https://<artifactorydomain.com>
```

to the new URL (adding the `/artifactory`):

```
https://<artifactorydomain.com>/artifactory
```

Hope this helps.